# download gitub artifact from url using wget

Tags: github, wget

I am trying to follow these docs to download an artifact from github using githubs API:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/artifacts#download-an-artifact

I ran the curl command given in the docs, and it gave me the following url from which to download the artifact (I have replaced the specifics with ...)

```
https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/serviceHosts/..../_apis/pipelines/1/runs/16/signedartifactscontent?artifactName=my-artifact&urlExpires=....&urlSigningMethod=HMACV2&urlSignature=....
```

I am able to download the artifact by putting the URL into my browser (it automatically downloads when the URL is visited) however I tried to use wget to download it via console and got this error:

```
wget https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/... # the command I ran

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request # the error I got
```

How can I download a zip file to console? Should I use something other than wget?

I'd like to clarify that viewing this link in the browser is possible even when not logged in to github (or when in private browsing). Also, I can download the zip file at the link as many times as I would like before the link expires after 1 minute. Also my repo is private, which is necessary for my work. I need to use an access token when doing the curl command as described in the docs, however the link that is returned to me does not require any authentication when accessed via a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't put quotes around my url. I needed to do this:

```
wget "https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/serviceHosts/..../_apis/pipelines/1/runs/16/signedartifactscontent?artifactName=my-artifact&urlExpires=....&urlSigningMethod=HMACV2&urlSignature=...."
```

Answer (score 1):

The api docs seem a bit ambiguous here. It is possible that the redirect can only be accessed a single time in which case you should try generating the redirect and first using wget to parse it. You can then unzip the file using the `unzip` command.

If that is not the case  I believe this statement in the api docs is key:

> Anyone with read access to the repository can use this endpoint. If the repository is private you must use an access token with the repo scope. GitHub Apps must have the actions:read permission to use this endpoint.

My guess is that your repository is private and you are logged in on the browser to Github which allows you to be authenticated hence why you are able to download from the redirect link. I would suggest trying from incognito mode to test this.

Migrating the repository to public would allow you to bypass this issue. Alternatively you can pass the authentication token as a header to wget like so in order to authenticate with the server to pull the file.

```
header='--header=Authorization: token <TOKEN>'
wget "$header" https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/... -O output_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have updated my question to address some of your points. I don't think the access token should be needed as I don't need to use it when downloading in the browser, even when I'm not logged into github.

Comment: hmm have you tried just using curl as a GET request with the redirect link? You can also try spoofing the user-agent with the utility to emulate grabbing the file as chrome or firefox, see https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/change-the-user-agent-in-wget/ for examples

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Turns out the problem was I needed quotes around the url as I explained in the solution I posted.